# Jest test can't import file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am start test component React with Jest and Enzyme, so I can't run test success with issue import file.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import './_rollupPluginBabelHelpers-3c58f0e3.js';                                              
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at node_modules/react-imask/dist/react-imask.js:2:83
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-imask/dist/react-imask.js:5:2)
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "jest": {
    "testResultsProcessor": "./node_modules/jest-junit-reporter",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": "['node_modules/(?!(imask)/)']"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@transwap/ui": "^2.0.1-rev182",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "formik": "2.1.4",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^1.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-query": "^2.23.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "2.1.6"
  },
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix  src/**/*.js"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm found solution by use **modulePathIgnorePatterns** in my override.config.js

```
    config.modulePathIgnorePatterns=["<rootDir>/node_modules/imask/esm"];
```